# Relational XY graph for each timestamp in Grafana

Tags: time-series, grafana, influxdb, flux

Lets suppose i have the following table data

```
Time  X1 Y1 X2 Y2
t1 …
t2 …
```

I need to do a X-Y graph with 2 lines (one for each time).
Each line connects points (X1,Y1) to (X2,Y2)

Is this even possible in grafana? If so how?

My data comes from InfluxDb

Best regards
Ricardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XY Chart panel do that natively. You can feed a table like the one you provided and create as much series as needed, telling which colum is X and which one is Y for each series. They don't need to be called X or Y either.

There is an auto detectection for series, but I am not sure of the expected format in the table (not documented and reading at the code I believe it's for X with multiples Y, not multiple series of pairs.)

[image: XY Chart panel in Grafana 10 with example data]

Answer (score 2):

For Grafana to visualize data in XYGraph it need to be in the format

| Time | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | X1 | Y1 |
| t1 | X2 | Y2 |
| t2 | X1 | Y1 |
| t2 | X2 | Y2 |

This can be done without elaborate queries. You need to add two queries: first providing X1, Y1 data, and second - X2, Y2 data.

After this you can apply transformation ***Merge***, to union provided data into a single dataset.

And then ***Partition by values*** with field *Time*, to that every row of initial dataset is visualized as independent graph.

Comment: What if I don't know how many X,Y pairs I will have? It is an undefined number. It's not practical to do queries for each pair, there could be dozens

Comment: @RicardoSantos, independently of number of pairs you should need only two queries all the time. I'm not familiar with influxdb, but in usual sql your queries wold be this: 1. `select time, x1 as x, y1 as y from table` and 2. `select time, x2 as x, y2 as y from table`